# How do I add back the scrollbar in mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've taken the scrollbar off of the header area on a page and it looks good except for on mobile (at least iPhone, I don't know about Android), where the scrollbar dissapears completely. How do I get it back?

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RgRWB/3/show)

Comment: you want the scrollbar to appear on your iphone or on the header?

Comment: not on the header. I want the scrollbar to appear on mobile/iphone. If you look at the page on both desktop and iphone, they currently look different. Scrolling isn't smooth on iphone and the scrollbar doesn't appear on the iphone

Comment: Is it necessary to have a scrollbar?

Comment: yes. As is, the scrolling on the iphone is not fluid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a different approach. Make the whole page scroll like normal (no `overflow-y`) and fix the header to the top via `position:fixed;` (I think that's what you wanted?)

Here's an edited version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TnKNe/

If that doesn't work, you could try [this jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller) which gives you complete control over the scrolling of an element. It says it has mobile support as well, but I have never used it before, so mileage may vary.

**Note:** `position:fixed;` is not support well or at all in Android. iOS4 and earlier treat it like `position:static;`. iOS5 and latest Android both support it though: http://caniuse.com/css-fixed

**Update:**

I found [this tutorial on content scrolling in ios5](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/ios-5-fixed-positioning-and-content-scrolling/) that looks like it's for you! The technique they use to get a fixed header with scrollable region in the middle apparently only works in ios5 and newer. They have [another tutorial doing the same thing with a plugin called iScroll](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/introduction-to-iscroll/) which looks to be more robust and works on Android as well. It looks like it's exactly what you wanted. Here's the [iScroll website](http://cubiq.org/iscroll).

Comment: that does seem to work in mobile. I'd rather not screw around with the header though.

Comment: I'm glad it's working. It's worth noting that it's only 4 extra lines on the header class (5 if you count background-color). Visually it's identical, so your users won't notice any difference. If you're just wanting to keep the header class clean, add a second class named .fixed-top and put the styles in that to fix an element to the top.

Answer (score -1):

On mobile, scrollbars are usually invisible until you start scrolling (dragging your finger across the screen). And even then they're just a thin indicator telling you where you are on the page, you can't actually touch it to move (only in certain apps/browsers).

The reason for that is that mobiles are narrow. You don't want to waste space with a scrollbar taking up 5-10% of your screen width.

Comment: but the scrollbar doesn't appear when you start to scroll.

Comment: @Mr.Gaga It does on Android. Why is it so important to have a scrollbar?